# Sumar datos de un JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un JTable con 2 columnas Precio y Producto, lo que quiero es sumar la columna Precio pero cuando le doy a mi botón para imprimir el precio solo me sale el ultimo valor, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void imprimirRecibo(){

  int totalRow=tabla.getRowCount();
  double total1=0;

  for(int i=0;i<totalRow;i++)
  {
    total=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(i, 0)));

  }

  total1+=total;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se imprime el recibo. El total ha pagar es " + total1);
}
```

Comment: La suma `total1+=total;`  debe ir dentro del `for`.

Comment: Hace falta tener pocas luces para no verlo jajaja, muchas gracias :)